# Make sure of cronjob is working !

Tags: cron

how i can make that every thing i put it in crontab is working? is there any logs for cron to see whether if worked successfully or not?

Answer (score 2):

There should be a log file here:

```
/var/log/cron.log
```

or similar.

Answer (score 1):

If your scheduled commands provide some output your can add something like

`> /home/your_user/log_dir/command.log` at the end of your cron job entry.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a line saying:

```
 MAILTO=your-mail.com
```

You will receive a mail then, when your cronjob gets executed.

Comment: Assuming a properly formatted email address (that is correct, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

if you on a nix box, you can add the line after the cron;

- 5 * * * /root/doacron.sh | mail -s 'subjecthere' me@mydomain.com

works well...

Comment: Script output is mailed to the owner of the crontab by default. It is not necessary to pipe it to mail. If you want to specify one or more other recipients you set the MAILTO variable. See `man 5 crontab`